# Unable to display correct array details when it is clickable using pipe filter

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I tried to implement search bar using pipe filter for my array which is clickable (something like the recipe list) and It filters my recipes by name. Its working fine, until I click on an item and it still has its old index, therefore giving me the wrong recipeDetails component (of another recipe). Can somebody please help me in solving this issue.

Pipe Filter code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {Recipe} from "../recipes/recipe.model";

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(recipes:Recipe[],filteredString:string): any {
    if(filteredString.length===0){
      return recipes
    }else{
      return recipes.filter(recipe=>recipe.name.toLowerCase().includes(filteredString.toLowerCase()));
    }
  }

}
```

Recipe Details Code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input id="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for a Recipe" [(ngModel)]="search">
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-recipes-list-item *ngFor="let recipe of (recipes |filter:search);let i=index" [recipe]="recipe" [index]="i"></app-recipes-list-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

Recipe Service code

```
import {Recipe} from "../recipes/recipe.model";
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Ingredient} from "../shared/ingredient.model";
import {ShoppingListService} from "./shopping-list.service";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

@Injectable()
export class RecipesService{
  recipeEmitted=new Subject<Recipe>();
  ingredientDeleted=new Subject<Recipe>();
  recipesChanged=new Subject<Recipe[]>();
 private recipes:Recipe[]=[new Recipe('Super Ecd asy Egg Casserole','http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/560x315/2195255.jpg','Another husband-approved recipe..',[new Ingredient('Apple',10),new Ingredient('Banana',10)]),
    new Recipe('Super Easy Egg Casserole','http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/560x315/2195255.jpg','Another husband-approved recipe. Made a couple times recently because of how easy it is to make! This recipe is easy to double or triple, but you may have to cook a bit longer if doing so.',[new Ingredient('Apple',10),new Ingredient('Banana',10)])
   ];
 constructor(private shoppingService:ShoppingListService){}

  getRecipes(){
    return this.recipes.slice();
  }
  getRecipe(id:number){
    return this.recipes[id];
  }
  deleteIngredient(recipeId:number,ingredientId:number){
    this.recipes[recipeId].ingredients.splice(ingredientId,1);
    this.ingredientDeleted.next(this.getRecipe(recipeId));
  }
  updateRecipe(id:number,recipe:Recipe){
    this.recipes[id]=recipe;
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.getRecipes());
  }
  addRecipe(recipe:Recipe){
    this.recipes.push(recipe);
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.getRecipes());
  }
 addIngredientsToShoppingList(ingredients:Ingredient[]){
    this.shoppingService.addRecipeIngredients(ingredients);
 }
}
```

Recipe List Item

```
<a style="{cursor:pointer}" [routerLink]="['/recipes',index]" routerLinkActive="active" class="list-group-item clearfix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{recipe.description}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <span class="pull-right">
        <img src="{{recipe.imageUrl}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:50px;"/>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Unclear. Where is the HTML and the code handling a click? Why do you use any index in the first place? The recipe should have an ID uniquely identifying it, and allowing to display its details.

Comment: It doesnt need an ID since the whole object is passed into the child component.

Comment: @NadunLiyanage unless the list only contains some information about each recipe, and the details need to be fetched based on the clicked item, which is what the question is suggesting. But until the OP clarifies, we can't say much.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with the `recipe` object instead of the index for processing within the click event. Since you are already passing the object to the `<app-recipes-list-item>` component, it will work that way.

Comment: Why the down vote? can you please comment whats wrong in it?

Comment: My array is a clickable one so to know which list item  i have clicked i need to know the index of it. so though i have passed the recipe object, I need index value to for editing the recipe or showing the recipe details

Comment: Use an @Output() variable of EventEmitter type and upon click of the component element call `emit(recipe)` and in the parent component catch that event and compare the returning recipe object against the array with a unique variable in that object.